# High CPU usage on couchbase server with moderate load

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-view

I am using Couchbase Server on stage environment. Things were working fine until yesterday. But since today I am observing **high CPU usage** when the load is increased moderately. (PFA)

[image: CouchbaseSnapshot]

**Couchbase cluster configuration**:-

1. 3 node cluster running (**4.5.1-2844 Community Edition (build-2844)**)
   each having **m4.2xlarge(8 cores, 32 GB RAM)** AWS machines.
2. Data RAM quota: 25000 MB
   Index RAM quota: 2048MB
3. It has 9 buckets. And used bucket is having 9 GB RAM (i.e. 3 GB per cluster)

***Note:*** - Since we are using community edition, each node is running Data, Full Text, Index, and query service.

Let me know if I've done some misconfiguration or if any optimization required.

Comment: I know this is an old issue, but if it's still relevant, you should specify what is that bit that have changed, what query are you executing, what index and what kind of view are you using.